# How do my child cards implement their own navigation header buttons in NavigationExperimental?

Tags: react-native, navigator

The NavigationHeader along with it's left and right buttons is defined in the root navigator card in the stack.  What if I wanted children in the stack to implement their own left and right button actions?  What is the best way to implement this?  Of course I don't want giant if/else blocks in the root navigator and the root navigator doesn't need to know it's child's implementations either.

```
  render () {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction='horizontal'
        navigationState={this.props.navigation}
        onNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)}
        renderOverlay={this._renderHeader.bind(this)}
        renderScene={this._renderScene} />
      )
  }

  _renderHeader(props) {
    const showHeader = props.scene.route.title &&
      (Platform.OS === 'ios' || props.scene.route.key === 'details');

    if (showHeader) {
      return (
        <NavigationHeader
        {...props}
        renderTitleComponent={this._renderTitleComponent.bind(this)}
        renderLeftComponent={this._renderLeftComponent.bind(this)}
        renderRightComponent={this._renderRightComponent.bind(this)}
        />
      );
    }

    return null;
  }

  _renderTitleComponent(props) {
    return (
      <NavigationHeader.Title>
        {props.scene.route.title}
      </NavigationHeader.Title>
    );
  }

  _renderLeftComponent(props) {
    const { dispatch, navigation } = this.props;

    if (props.scene.route.key === 'chat_overview') {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={this.props._handleMenu}>
          <Text>Menu</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    else if (props.scene.route.showBackButton) {
      return (
        <NavigationHeaderBackButton onNavigate={() => dispatch(popRoute(navigation.key))} />
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
```